# Apache2 Password protect directory but allow local access without password prompt

Tags: linux, apache2

I am using apache2 webserver and have configured directory protection which works OK. However On the pc that is hosting my apache2 webserver I need to access the site without apache2 prompting for username and password. I have tried many of the suggested solutions out there but have not been able to get this darn thing to work. At the moment I am forced to enter username/password to access the site from the same machine ? This is my apache2.conf setup --- any help would be most appreciated.

```
<Directory /var/www>
AuthName Login
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /usr/local/bin/passwords
Require valid-user
Allow from 127.0.0.1
Satisfy Any
</Directory>
```

The above is the basic setup I have but I hav tried a number of variations to this but still cannot seem to access my site from the local machine (that host's the site) via firefox.
My apache2 server is also configured to operate on port 888 rather that the normal port 80 - I need to do this because my local ISP blocks port 80?

I need to access the local site from the server machine using firefox but without it asking for username & passwords (required only for external access)

Answer (score 0):

You may check the directive [Satisfy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/auth.html#satisfy) again and have a look to the directive [location](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#location)

Edit: Your question may also be a duplicate of [this one](https://serverfault.com/a/86403/72358)